# How to repeat within an iMacros script?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a little experience with iMacros but this is above my knowledge level (especially since this may end up being a javascript question). I have five different GOTO urls. On each page, I want to click a button 20 times. The button is the same on all five pages. I want the macro to stop after it has gone through each set of pages five times.

I hope that's clear. Feel free to ask any questions.

Thanks for any help you're able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. Increase the url's as per your requirements. Just re-run the script 5 times or change the loop so that it runs 5 times for each link.
This is a javascript code, save it in same folder, where your imacros files are there with .js extension

```
var urls = 
['http://www.url_1.com',
'http://www.url_2.com',
'http://www.url_3',
'http://www.url_4',
'http://www.url_5']

for (var i in urls) {
  var url = urls[i];
  var returnCode = iimPlay('CODE: URL GOTO='+url);
  iimPlay("C:\\Users\\Venkat\\Documents\\iMacros\\Macros\\#macro_script_name");    
}
```

in the place of macro_script_name -- please replace that with the imacros script which clicks the button 20 times in the webpage